# How do I parse python script variables to tcl or c++?

Tags: python, c++, tcl

I am creating a program that uses two different softwares however unfortunately one  only supports Python for its API and the other either tcl or c++ , I have successfully used the Python API to gather the variables required, however I need to parse these variables to the other script coded in either tcl or c++ (Havent developed this side yet so the language doesn't matter).

How can I parse the variables from one script to the other? Would it be easier to parse to tcl or c++?

Comment: Generally, most languages have the ability to call command line scripts and pass info through stdout.  You just need to choose a format both languages can parse -- json, xml, csv -- and pass that through stdout and stdin.

Comment: @Tolki , The best way would be to create an intermediate output from each script and use that as the input for the other. 
`python script1.py > output_of_python.txt`
`./cppbinary < output_of_python.txt > output_of_cpp_with_py_input.txt`

Comment: Very broad and abiguous. Are you saying that you're trying to bind the python and tcl engine to C++ and use it directly, or simply take some version of serialized I/O (language specific script literals of one form or another) and then use it? It seems like the later. Correct?

Comment: re these "two different softwares" combined into a single executable where one language embeds the other? Are these two different programs that run in two different processes? How are they connected?

Comment: It depends on the skill you have on the languages. If you know *c++* and no *tcl*, than *c++* should be the esiest. If you know both: *tcl* of course. But if you know both, you should already know that. :) If you have to learn one language than choose *tcl* as it is easy than *c++* for this kind of tasks. If the amaunt of data is huge or you have performance issues, than you have to learn both languages and check which fit better.

Comment: If your python environment provides access to the `tkinter` module, you already have a working Tcl interpreter on your python side, so talking with a Tcl based API on the other side can be pretty easy.